# PSQL: How can I return a value from a select query, but if the resultset is null return a default vaule?

Tags: postgresql

```
  DECLARE _retention bigint := (SELECT retention_days
          FROM   retention_period
          WHERE  fulfilment_type = 'daily');
```

If the SELECT query returns null because "daily" doesn't exist in the retention_period table, how can I return a default value please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Postgres [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to set a default value.

```
DECLARE _retention bigint := coalesce((SELECT retention_days as retention_days
          FROM   retention_period
          WHERE  fulfilment_type = 'daily'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the COALESCE function like so:

```
DECLARE _retention bigint := COALESCE(
(SELECT retention_days FROM retention_period WHERE fulfilment_type = 'daily'),
default_value);
```

replace '*default_value*' with the actual value you want here e.g. 0.

**COALESCE** is a function used to return the first non-null argument from a list of provided arguments.
The syntax is:
*COALESCE (argument_1, argument_2, …);*